# Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) docker container

Tags: apt, docker, wget, kubernetes

when I want to install wget in docker container like this:

```
exec kubectl exec -i -t -n reddwarf-storage reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0 -c reddwarf-postgresql -- sh -c "clear; (bash || ash || sh)"
➜  ~ exec kubectl exec -i -t -n reddwarf-storage reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0 -c reddwarf-postgresql -- sh -c "clear; (bash
 || ash || sh)"
sh: 1: clear: not found
I have no name!@reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0:/$ apt-get install wget
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
I have no name!@reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0:/$ sudo apt-get install wget
bash: sudo: command not found
```

then I tried to switch to root:

```
I have no name!@reddwarf-postgresql-postgresql-0:/$ su -
Password:
```

I did not know the root password of the docker container. what should I do to install wget in the docker container?

Comment: Is the Pod running Ubuntu? If not, this is off topic here

Comment: yes, the Pod is running in Ubuntu.@muru

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?